# IdentityServer3 and php

Tags: php

How to connect `identityServer3` to php application. I have application in asp.net MVC which is using IDS3 now i need to connect php client app with SSO integration base on IDS3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is less a question about IdentityServer3, and more a question of what OpenID Connect libraries are recommended for PHP.
http://openid.net/developers/libraries/
The OpenID web site lists three OIDC libraries for relying parties - the right one to choose depends on your web server (nginx, Apache) and application stack (e.g. Drupal).

Recommend you try the most lightweight first and see if it supports what you need. 
https://github.com/jumbojett/OpenID-Connect-PHP

Comment: Thanks i ll look into.

Answer (score -2):

I am implementing same type of auth but get client secret validator error, do you have any docs? I m using openid-oauth2 library